Set Cookie in browser is not being persisted
I have an express code that sends the cookie to get requests in some route:
res.cookie("userID", `${userSaved._id}`, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });

So when I make a get request in this route the response header has Set-Cookie : USERID : 234232,
I have another route where I want to use this cookie, but on the request header I don't see any cookie persisted.
I'm using React as a front-end and node as a backend.
I have tried modifying my cors middleware,
In react in fetch() I have put credentials : include,

This might answer your question-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/78682580/21210375

There are 2 types of cookie, one for Session cookie, much like the SessionStorage, will remove while the client is closed. one for Permanent cookie, removed at a specific date (Expires) or after a specific length of time (Max-Age) and not when the client is closed.
I would suggest you to check the response header, whether returns like this:
Set-Cookie: userID=xxxx; maxAge=900000

The MDN describe like this:

Session cookie

Session cookies are removed when the client shuts down. Cookies are session cookies if they do not specify the Expires or Max-Age attribute.
Set-Cookie: sessionId=38afes7a8


Permanent cookie

Permanent cookies are removed at a specific date (Expires) or after a specific length of time (Max-Age) and not when the client is closed.
Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT

Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Max-Age=2592000


It is being returned as a permanent cookie but it did not persist with the post requests that i make.

How did you send your post requests? please give more detail information.

Fetch (url,{mode:’cors’,method:’Post’, headers:{content-type : ‘json/application’)})

If a cors request is made, the credentials option should be setted. view the information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RequestInit#credentials

Yes, I set the credentials and it worked thanks Jacy.
